# How can I apply a PID controller in a difference equation form on Scilab to a continuous plant

Tags: filter, scilab, pid-controller

I just calculated the difference form equation for a PID control and I need to evaluate it in scilab, now, the question that I how to add the difference equation to the system to see if the controller is doing what is expected.

I saw in this [document](https://www.scilab.org/discrete-time-pid-controller-implementation) how to do it in Xcos but I want to make it by program or console since I programmed an application to do those calculations.

I've been readind that using the function [filter](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/en_US/filter.html) I can apply the equation as a z-transform to the signal I want but I don't know if I could use the difference equation. Another doubt that I have is, in case of using filter, how to put the error as an input to filter.

Comment: Can you give the difference equation of your pid and the one of your system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do everything discrete (system and controller) then the simplest way is to run the discrete time loop yourself. For example if your equations look like:

```
 - System: x[k]=A*x[k-1]+B*u[k-1], y[k]=C*x[k]
 - Error: e[k]=yd[k]-y[k-1]
 - Integral: i[k]=i[k-1]+Ts*(e[k]+e[k-1])/2
 - Derivative: d[k]=(e[k]-e[k-1])/Ts 
 - Control equation: u[k]=Kp*e[k]+Ki*i[k]+Kd*d[k]
```

you just have to write the above in Scilab (I have supposed that your state is a vector but output and control are scalars, yd is the output to track):

```
x(:,1)=x0;
u=zeros(1,N);
y=zeros(1,N);
e=zeros(1,N);
yd=ones(1,N);
i=0;
for k=2:N
    x(:,k)=A*x(:,k-1)+B*u(k-1)
    y(k)=C*x(:,k)
    e(k)=yd(k)-y(k)
    i=i+Ts*(e(k)+e(k-1))/2
    d=(e(k)-e(k-1))/Ts
    u(k)=Kp*e(k)+Ki*i+Kd*d 
end
```

The above can be simplified if you don't need all the signal history (I already did it above for the integral and derivative parts).

Another possibility is to use `ltitr`(see https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/ltitr.html) but in that case you have to express your closed loop system in standard (A,B) form.

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Mottelet, sorry for the delay, thanks for the help and the answer.